# SQL name workers with only 5 characters

Tags: sql

I have a database with workers and their names. How can I get a list of the workers whose name contains only 5 characters

Comment: When using [LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like:~:text=_%20matches%20exactly%20one%20character.), the `_` will  exactly one character.

Comment: But length is the right operator. I don't see an alternative that wouldn't be terrible. (like the `LIKE` approach: That's a pretty complex query, while using `LEN` is as simple as it gets.)

Comment: Create another table and fill it with all combinations of 5 characters of your alphabet. Then join the island name with that table.

Comment: @treuss; Can you specify how many records are in the table  "with all combinations of 5 characters" ? 

Comment: @Luuk This depends on the alphabet you use. I'm sorry, any time I see a question which states "but I don't want to use the most obvious/common approach", I start thinking about what is the most absurd approach to the same problem. And 26 to the power of 5 is not thaaaaaat much...

Comment: You are right [26^5](https://www.google.com/search?q=26%5E5)is only 11881376, but you also might have capitals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE island_name LIKE '_____'
```

Comment: Used this approach, thaks a lot it worked! :)

Comment: Be aware of using 'LIKE' on front. ex, `SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE promocode LIKE '________'`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE REPLICATE('A',LEN(island_name)) = 'AAAAA'
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree that `LENGTH` is the best option.  Maybe this is a school question.

Give this a try:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(field1,1,5) 
FROM table1 
WHERE substr(field1,5,1) IS NOT NULL 
    AND SUBSTR(segment1,6,999) IS NULL;;
```

Comment: You will show the first 5 letters of Islands with 6 or more letters on their name.

Comment: Check: `select substr(island,1,5) from (select 'isla' as island) islands where substr(island,5,1) is not null and
substr(island,6,999) is null;`

Answer (score -1):

You could use `SUBSTRING()`, if you are looking for an alternative method. You can check if a `SUBSTRING of X characters == The Original String`.

However, you would also need to account for 4-character strings, for example. You could add "padding characters", or you could make sure that `X-1 Character Substring != X-character Substring`. In Sql 2016 for example, these are the same with at least one case of query options:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ISLA',1,4)
SELECT SUBSTRING('ISLA',1,5)
```